# Pandas read_sql_query raises TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Im using `pandas.read_sql_query()` to read from a database and directly convert the query result to a dataframe.

```
 for df in pd.read_sql_query(
                con=some_conn,
                sql=some_sql,
                params={
                    "some_list": ",".join(some_list),
                    "some_other_list": ",".join(some_other_list),
                },
                chunksize=chunk_size,
                dtype=dtype_columns,
            ):
```

Im also providing `dtype` argument [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html). Among other dtype includes `<class 'numpy.int16'> and <class 'numpy.int8'>`

Im getting back a `TypeError` coming from pandas .astype():

```
File ".../pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 526, in astype     new_values = astype_array_safe(values, dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
File ".../pandas/core/dtypes/astype.py", line 299, in astype_array_safe     new_values = astype_array(values, dtype, copy=copy)
File ".../pandas/core/dtypes/astype.py", line 230, in astype_array     values = astype_nansafe(values, dtype, copy=copy)
File ".../pandas/core/dtypes/astype.py", line 170, in astype_nansafe     return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'
```

Apparently the db contains corrupted/NULL/None data which pandas, for a good reason, fails to convert it to `int`.

Is there any good way to fix that while using `pandas.read_sql_query` or I have to fetch the data from the db -> clean it -> convert it to df?

Comment: Post your code and data. The error says that you tried to read a NULL as an int. That's not corrupted data. It means the series type is wrong. You need to use [specialized nullable integer types](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na) like Int32Dtype. Pandas in general has several issues with NULL handling, even between minor versions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't post the data as I dont have direct access to it, try to avoid to read using sqlalchemy. Indeed, it seems that there is some NULL value where an int should exist.

Comment: You do have access, otherwise `read_sql_query` wouldn't work at all. You didn't post the important part of the code either, the dtypes. Somewhere in there you specified `int`. Use the appropriate nullable type instead, like Int32Dtype, Int64Dtype, Int8Dtype etc

Comment: It runs via a pipeline. I see <class 'numpy.int16'> and <class 'numpy.int8'>

Comment: You still didn't post what `dtype_columns` contains. That's a dictionary though. You can easily replace any integer types with `Int8Dtype` and `Int16Dtype`. [Read the documentation link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na) I posted earlier